# SmoothBottomBar kotlin

Tags: android, bottombar

https://github.com/ibrahimsn98/SmoothBottomBar
I am making the smoothBottomBar shared by a friend in Java, but when I want to make it in Kotlin, I get an error in the mainactivity codes. Example 1: Type in the object section, Example 2: Boolean
Can anyone share appropriate MainActivity codes for Kotlin?
My code

```
package com.paranoyaq.iconoynatilantabvenav

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
import me.ibrahimsn.lib.OnItemSelectedListener
import me.ibrahimsn.lib.SmoothBottomBar

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var smoothBottomBar: SmoothBottomBar
    private lateinit var toolbar: Toolbar

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        smoothBottomBar = findViewById(R.id.bottombar)
        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar)
        smoothBottomBar.setOnItemSelectedListener { pos ->
                when (pos) {
                    0 -> {
                        val fragmentManager = supportFragmentManager
                        val fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.framelayout, HomeFragment())
                        fragmentTransaction.commit()
                        true
                    }
                    1 -> {
                        val fragmentManager = supportFragmentManager
                        val fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.framelayout, SettingFragment())
                        fragmentTransaction.commit()
                        true
                    }
                    2 -> {
                        val fragmentManager = supportFragmentManager
                        val fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.framelayout, PersonFragment())
                        fragmentTransaction.commit()
                        true
                    }
                    3 -> {
                        val fragmentManager = supportFragmentManager
                        val fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.framelayout, MoreFragment())
                        fragmentTransaction.commit()
                        true
                    }
                }
                false
            }
        }

    }
```